# How to enable manual row move in a shiny rhandsontable?

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I have been trying to figure out how to enable row moving in an R shiny handson table.  As described here: https://handsontable.com/docs/6.2.1/demo-moving.html.  I cant seem to figure out how to pass the parameter to the Handson table.

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("rhandsontable test"),

      # Show a plot of the generated distribution
      mainPanel(
        rHandsontableOutput("test")
      )
   )


# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

   output$test <- renderRHandsontable({
     rhandsontable(iris)
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but for me `rhandsontable(iris, manualColumnMove = TRUE, manualRowMove = TRUE)` works as expected!

Comment: Worked for me too.  Thought I tried that but I guess not.  Thanks so much!